# How To Create Interface That Uses the Class that Extends It

Tags: c++-cli

I'm writing some hypothetical code for practice, and I came across a design issue.

Suppose that I have a class GameObject:

```
public ref class GameObject : GameObjectBluePrint {
public:
    property double health;
    property double damage;
    property double defense;
    property double strideLength;
    property System::Drawing::Point location;

public:
    virtual void Attack(GameObject% enemy) {
        enemy.health -= this->damage;
    }
    virtual void Defend(GameObject% enemy) {
        this->health -= enemy.damage * 0.5;
    }
    virtual void Move(Direction direction) {
        switch (direction) {
        case Direction::up:
            this->location.Y += this->strideLength;
            break;
        case Direction::down:
            this->location.Y -= this->strideLength;;
            break;
        case Direction::right:
            this->location.X += this->strideLength;;
            break;
        case Direction::left:
            this->location.X -= this->strideLength;
            break;
        }
    }
    virtual bool isVisible(GameObject% otherObject) {
        double distance = Math::Sqrt(Math::Pow(this->location.X - otherObject.location.X, 2) + Math::Pow(this->location.Y - otherObject.location.Y, 2));
        return distance <= 2;
    }
};
```

And I want to make different types of these objects, so I create an interface that this class extends:

```
public interface class GameObjectBluePrint {
    void Attack(GameObject% enemy);
    void Defend(GameObject% enemy);
    void Move(Direction direction);
    bool isVisible(GameObject% otherObject);
};
```

The issue is that this interface relies on the GameObject class being defined first. However, for the GameObject class to be defined, I have to extend this interface. Am I going about this interface concept incorrectly, or is there a way to avoid nested messes like this one?

Comment: How about this pattern?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: anything new? is the answer sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

How about combine the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2kb28261.aspx

```
generic <typename TGameObject>  
public interface class class GameObjectBluePrint {
    void Attack(TGameObject% enemy);
    void Defend(TGameObject% enemy);
    void Move(Direction direction);
    bool isVisible(TGameObject% otherObject);
};

public ref class GameObject : GameObjectBluePrint<GameObject> {
...
}
```